# <table> <tr> selector in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am using `$('#tbl-' + no + ' tr')` (where `var no = 'one'`) to calculate the length of `<tr>` in a table, this works fine sometimes but sometimes it gives error.

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #tbl-[object HTMLSelectElement]

is there some another way to select the `<tr>`?

Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitlamba009/sa44j/)

Javascript function in my project :

```
function createAgentList(list, campaign) {
alert("table rows : " + $('#liveAgentTable-' + campaign + ' tr').length);
$('#liveAgentTable-' + campaign + ' tr').has('td').remove();

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr class="agnt_tr" value="user"></tr>').appendTo('#liveAgentTable-' + campaign);
    var radioBtn = $('<input type="radio" name="radioAgent" value="' + list[i].name + '" />"  id="radioAgent' + list[i].name + '"');
    tr.append(radioBtn);
    tr.append("<td>" + list[i].name + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + list[i].extension + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + list[i].skill + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + list[i].phoneNumber + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + list[i].status + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + list[i].callType + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + list[i].time + "</td>");
}
}
```

HTML Table:

```
<table id="liveAgentTable-<s:property />" class="agent_table" border="1" value="campaignId" style="width: 100%">

                    <tr>
                        <th>Select</th>
                        <th>Agent Name</th>
                        <th>Extension</th>
                        <th>Skill</th>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Call Type</th>
                        <th>HH:MM:SS</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

> `<s:property />` is campaign name coming by iterating campaign list

Comment: Define sometimes so that we can reproduce

Comment: please provide HTML and JS code

Comment: your fiddle is working fine...

Comment: Yeh, I can't reproduce your issue. the JSFiddle works fine!

Comment: It works fine in my fiddle but not in my real project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the variable `no` elsewhere in your code?

It's saying that `no = [object HTMLSelectElement]`, which is not a string, but an html element. This makes me wonder if elsewhere you've done something like `var no = $('#choice')` or something.

Try using a more descriptive variable.

Or instead try doing something like:

`$('table:first-child')` or `$('table:nth-child(5)')` etc.